# Find all rational solutions to $x^3 - y^2 = 2$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, contest-math, elliptic-curves

Find all rational solutions to $x^3 - y^2 = 2$.

The only integers solutions are $(3,\pm5)$:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180817001523/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51569.html)

Comment: See Mordell-Bachet, rational solutions of $y^2=x^3-2$.

Comment: The equation $y^2 = x^3+k$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is called Mordell-Bachet equation. An excellent resource for this is [Keith Conrad's article](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf), where he discusses integer solutions. Your problem is on page $6$, theorem $3.4$.

Comment: See J. W. S. Cassels, *The rational solutions of the diophantine equation $y^2 = x^3 - D.$* Acta Arithmetica, volume **82** (1950) pages 243-273.